# connecting contentful CMS with gatsby page

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, gatsby, contentful

I am trying to connect contentful and Gatsby for a blog.

```js
const path = require('path');

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, boundActionCreators }) => {
  const { createPage } = boundActionCreators;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/blog-post.js');
    resolve(
      graphql(`
        {
          allContentfulBlog(limit: 100) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
          reject(result.errors);
        }
        result.data.allContentfulBlog.edges.forEach(edge => {
          createPage({
            path: edge.node.slug,
            component: blogPostTemplate,
            context: {
              slug: edge.node.slug
            }
          });
        });
        return;
      })
    );
  });
};
```

This is what I wrote in the gatsby-node.js. When I do npm run develop, it gives me an error, saying "  TypeError: Cannot read property 'allContentfulBlog' of undefined." I am not sure how I should fix this. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: What's the name of your content Type, it should be Blog. does gatsby output somthin about the graphql query ?

Comment: I named it Blog. mmm with the error mentioned up there, it says "- gatsby-node.js:23 graphql.then.result" besides this, I can't find anything specific about graphql query.

Comment: I logged "result" to the console after the promise resolves, and that it gives me this error > GraphQLError: Cannot query field "slug" on type "ContentfulBlog".

Comment: Do you have a field slug in that content type, maybe it’s an upper case Slug instead?

Comment: I found out that in JSON Preview, there were only "titletext" instead of "slug". I changed all "slug" to "titletext" from atom, but it still gave an error saying: "GraphQL Error Unknown field `title` on type `ContentfulBlog`"  from blog-post.js, pageQuery graphql.

Comment: same error  , how can do fix this ?

Comment: Hi, I'm rlly sorry for late reply. It probsably requires you to edit a little bit of graphql.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same difficulties, I'm assuming you were following [this youtube tutorial by khaled](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek4o40w1tH4) and try to check it out by using the default contentful Blog template like so:

[image]

Make sure you are using the CORRECT contentModelName when writing the **allContentful{contentModelName} post**. When using the default blog example for contentful the title shows up as "Blog Post". Just change it from "Blog Post" to "Blog" and everything should be working fine if you followed Khaled's steps and added the "new Promise" fix (which I see you already did).

[image]

Good luck!